# Send json data from Flask API in faster way

Tags: pandas, postgresql, psycopg2, flask-restful

I have a postgresql table in db. I am fetching a data based on date and getting 70000 records and 25 columns on daily basis.
Fetching data from table using psycopg2 and pd.io.sql.read_sql
In flask api converting the data to json format
e.g. [{col1: data1, col2: data2,....., col25:data25},{col1: data1, col2: data2,....., col25:data25},......]

Now I want to send the data from the table using flask api in the json format. The task is performed in around 4 min. So it is taking so much time. Would you please help to write a optimised code to send the data in faster way.

Simple code to read from table using psycopg2 and pd.io.sql
Flask API code to send response jsonify method

Comment: How long does this query take?  `select jsonb_agg(my_table) from my_table where date = <somedate>`

Comment: query is simple as : select * from table where date = 'yyyy-mm-dd'. it takes 1 min 15 seconds to fetch data from postgresql to pandas dataframe. the total time for end to end process ( fetch data from postgresql to pandas, convert it to json and send as response is 4 min 20 sec.

Comment: That is not what I asked you.  How long does the query I put in my comment take to run in a query tool?

Comment: Ohh. My bad. I will try this and let you know. Thank you

Comment: Executed this query and got an error "missing from-clause entry for table my_table"

Comment: Change the table names from `my_table` to whatever your table's name is.

Comment: I tried the same query with table name I am using in my db, not "my_table".

Comment: How can that be?  https://dbfiddle.uk/NSjeb2jr